# Performance of PHP file_exists() vs. htaccess -f condition

Tags: php, performance, file, .htaccess, exists

I want to redirect to static html-files if they exist in a subdirectory.

I'm wondering if a little php script would be more performant as a htaccess RewriteCond.

Has somebody expiriences with that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it via mode_rewrite (in httpd.conf or in .htaccess) will be more efficient than doing it via a PHP script.

Just think about it, doing it in PHP will require Apache to load mod_php module and then PHP interpreter will be called and your PHP script will be compiled and executed. All that can be skipped if you handle it in .htaccess itself.

Comment: Do you have any basis for that claim? I'm not arguing that it's wrong  but it's fairly baseless and may well be. The .htaccess file must be loaded by apache, parsed and executed. Regular expressions are slow and both a PHP script or mod_rewrite need to stat the file.

Comment: @TomB: .htaccess will be there anyway (usually) on a website OR OP can put this rule in httpd.conf itself and avoid using .htaccess completely.

Comment: But `htaccess` files are read on every request and each rule is parsed. Doesn't that hit performance.Explained on this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) Moreover mods are loaded when apache boots up so will `mod_php`

Comment: @anubhava That's still an assumption without any evidence, you may well be correct but really the only way is some documented benchmarks

Comment: @tom-b: anubhava is correct, benchmarks or not. In the case of a non-fcgi site the difference may be fairly noticeable [depending on server load] since PHP won't have to do a full startup for each request. In the case of an fcgi site the advantage *still* goes to htaccess, but probably only to the tune of saving a couple seconds *per month*.

Comment: Thanks for your rating. I'm thinking the same way, but I had the hope that somebody had practical experiences with that.